# How can I turn .apply in kotlin into java, I can't find .apply in java at all

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment, addToBackStack: Boolean = false, ) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(fragmentContainer.id, fragment)
            if (addToBackStack) addToBackStack(null)
            commit()
        }
    }
```

This is the kotlin code

```
private loadFragment(Fragment fragment, Boolean addToBackStack){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(){

        }

    }
```

This is the java code
I have no way to add .apply after beginTransaction()
What should I do to use .apply

Comment: To Get a better Idea . Go to `Tools →  Kotlin → Show Kotlin Bytecode` and then press Decompile it will show you actual Java code which is being used internally .

Answer (score 4):

Overall, I recommend that you learn and start using Kotlin, sooner rather than later. In a few years, Java programming will be uncommon in Android app development.

`apply()` is simply a convenience function. An equivalent Kotlin function is:

```kotlin
private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment, addToBackStack: Boolean = false, ) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        transaction.replace(fragmentContainer.id, fragment)
            
        if (addToBackStack) transaction.addToBackStack(null)

        transaction.commit()
    }
```

The Java equivalent would be something like:

```java
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(fragmentContainer.id, fragment);
            
        if (addToBackStack) transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();
    }
```